# Does hybridizing a specific flower affect the offspring?

Tags: flowers

If among several flowers within a plant, there is a specific flower that is slightly larger or brighter or has an extra petal, will this trait be possibly passed on to the offspring? In other words, does picking a specific flower to hybridize matter and impact the offspring or does the offspring inherit the general traits of the whole plant and any flower has the same impact? Just wondering if when hybriding a plant, I need to be selective on which flower to choose.